# Bamboo agent JVM exited unexpectedly

Tags: java, docker, jvm, bamboo

I am trying to run the Bamboo agent in the newly set up server. However, when I start running it, it keeps repeating the same things over and over again. And at the end of all, it says 'JVM exited unexpectedly.' Below, I am providing the log output.

> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:10:57 | 2023-07-21 14:10:57,474 INFO [AgentRunnerThread] [AgentRegistrationBean] Current agent remote definition: prometaubuntu Remote agent on host prometaubuntu
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:10:57 | 2023-07-21 14:10:57,489 INFO [AgentRunnerThread] [PerforceManager] Could not find system variable. If you wish to use perforce please set the location as a capability.
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:10:58 | 2023-07-21 14:10:58,853 INFO [AgentRunnerThread] [AgentRegistrationBean] Registering agent on the server,
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | 2023-07-21 14:15:14,149 ERROR [ActiveMQ Task-1] [FailoverTransport] Failed to connect to [tcp://bamboosrv:54663?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=300000] after: 10 attempt(s)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | 2023-07-21 14:15:14,161 INFO [ActiveMQ Connection Executor: unconnected] [PooledConnectionFactory] Expiring connection ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:prometaubuntu-46739-1689937858912-1:1,clientId=ID:prometaubuntu-46739-1689937858912-0:1,started=false} on IOException: bamboosrv
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | 2023-07-21 14:15:14,171 WARN [AgentRunnerThread] [RemoteAgent$1] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'agentRegistrationBean': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access JMS invoker queue [queue://com.atlassian.bamboo.registrationQueue]; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: javax.jms.JMSException: bamboosrv
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | 2023-07-21 14:15:14,174 INFO [AgentRunnerThread] [SVNClientManagerFactory] Destroying SVNClientManagerFactories...
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | 2023-07-21 14:15:14,183 INFO [AgentRunnerThread] [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler scheduler_$*NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | 2023-07-21 14:15:14,184 INFO [AgentRunnerThread] [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler scheduler*$*NON_CLUSTERED paused.
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | 2023-07-21 14:15:14,185 INFO [AgentRunnerThread] [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler scheduler*$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | Exiting due to fatal exception.
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.bootstrap.AgentRunner.run(AgentRunner.java:26)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'agentRegistrationBean': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access JMS invoker queue [queue://com.atlassian.bamboo.registrationQueue]; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: javax.jms.JMSException: bamboosrv
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:139)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1763)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:95)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.RemoteAgent$1.(RemoteAgent.java:241)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.RemoteAgent.initApplicationContext(RemoteAgent.java:241)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.RemoteAgent.start(RemoteAgent.java:97)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   ... 6 more
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | Caused by: org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access JMS invoker queue [queue://com.atlassian.bamboo.registrationQueue]; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: javax.jms.JMSException: bamboosrv
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.convertJmsInvokerAccessException(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:432)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:207)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.registerAgent(Unknown Source)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.AgentRegistrationBean.registerAgent(AgentRegistrationBean.java:52)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   ... 22 more
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: javax.jms.JMSException: bamboosrv
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.createSession(ConnectionPool.java:162)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnection.createSession(PooledConnection.java:167)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.createSession(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:281)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:250)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:204)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   ... 33 more
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: bamboosrv
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:72)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1421)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1486)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:329)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.makeSession(ConnectionPool.java:112)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool$1.makeObject(ConnectionPool.java:82)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool$1.makeObject(ConnectionPool.java:78)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.create(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1073)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:348)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:271)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.createSession(ConnectionPool.java:144)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   ... 37 more
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: bamboosrv
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.connect(TcpTransport.java:525)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doStart(TcpTransport.java:488)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:55)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.start(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:169)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.start(InactivityMonitor.java:52)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.start(WireFormatNegotiator.java:72)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.doReconnect(FailoverTransport.java:1017)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport$2.iterate(FailoverTransport.java:148)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   ... 1 more
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | 2023-07-21 14:15:14,226 FATAL [AgentRunnerThread] [AgentBootstrap] Exiting due to fatal exception.
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.bootstrap.AgentRunner.run(AgentRunner.java:26)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'agentRegistrationBean': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access JMS invoker queue [queue://com.atlassian.bamboo.registrationQueue]; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: javax.jms.JMSException: bamboosrv
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:139)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1763)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:95)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.RemoteAgent$1.(RemoteAgent.java:241)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.RemoteAgent.initApplicationContext(RemoteAgent.java:241)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.RemoteAgent.start(RemoteAgent.java:97)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   ... 6 more
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | Caused by: org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access JMS invoker queue [queue://com.atlassian.bamboo.registrationQueue]; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: javax.jms.JMSException: bamboosrv
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.convertJmsInvokerAccessException(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:432)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:207)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.registerAgent(Unknown Source)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.AgentRegistrationBean.registerAgent(AgentRegistrationBean.java:52)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   ... 22 more
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: javax.jms.JMSException: bamboosrv
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.createSession(ConnectionPool.java:162)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnection.createSession(PooledConnection.java:167)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.createSession(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:281)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:250)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:204)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   ... 33 more
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: bamboosrv
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:72)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1421)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1486)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:329)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.makeSession(ConnectionPool.java:112)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool$1.makeObject(ConnectionPool.java:82)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool$1.makeObject(ConnectionPool.java:78)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.create(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1073)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:348)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:271)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.createSession(ConnectionPool.java:144)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   ... 37 more
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: bamboosrv
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.connect(TcpTransport.java:525)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doStart(TcpTransport.java:488)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:55)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.start(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:169)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.start(InactivityMonitor.java:52)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.start(WireFormatNegotiator.java:72)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.doReconnect(FailoverTransport.java:1017)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport$2.iterate(FailoverTransport.java:148)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 |   ... 1 more
> ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/07/21 14:15:14 | JVM exited unexpectedly.
> STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/07/21 14:15:20 | JVM process is gone.

Comment: The error is not very readable, but it looks like it's the same as this one https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/FATAL-ERROR-Bamboo-Remote-Agent-is-loading-constently/qaq-p/1041828 In your stacktrace you have `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: bamboosrv`